Broadcom BCM4313 Wifi not working on Ubuntu 20.04
My old Broadcom Wifi card only works intermittently on Ubuntu 20.04.
I can see wireless networks and connect to them, but can't even ping anything once connected. When hotspoting from my phone, I got slightly better results, but still some very slow (<0.1 Mbps) connection sometimes.
The hardware seems to work fine, as it works well when I boot in Windows.
I already tried the steps described here and in a few other places:

Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers

My card is:

sudo lspci -nn -d 14e4:
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)


Please edit the question and add what you did from the -few other places- Also add any errors or messages you get.
